# Activation Records and Arrays in Fortran (or languages that have all Static Environments)

Tags: arrays, static, fortran, records, activation

When creating an array, how does a language like fortran make activation records when it is in an all static environment (because it doesn't know the size of the array during compile time)? I know it uses passing by reference so does that mean in the activation record it stores a reference instead of an array, which allows it to store a reference to an array that has not been made yet?

Comment: What do you mean by all static environment? You must understand that the same array can be looked in very different ways and can use an array descriptor in one scope and a simple pointer in a different scope.

Comment: Also, Fortran does not pass by a simple reference. And when it does the descriptor is often not needed, just a pointer.

Comment: So how does it use activation records then? How does it make a space in the activation record for an unspecified size array?

Comment: I really can't answer, because you didn't answer me. Again: What do you mean by all static environment? What kind of specific situation you have in mind? Some Fortran arrays are just like C pointers with some multi-D indexing under the hood, really.

Answer (score 1):

You might be confused because it is usually said that, in many implementations of FORTRAN, there is a single activation record for each subprogram that can be allocated statically as an extension of the code segment. (see for example: 4th edition of "Programming Languages, Design and implementation" by T. W. Pratt & M. V. Zelkowitz.)

Something to keep in mind is that even in that case, the activation record is always populated during execution, only the space is allocated statically. That is simple to understand since there can be many many calls to the same subprogram. And all those calls share the same activation record, only one call being alive at each time.

More importantly, the array data are not included in the activation record. Passing argument by reference means that there is not duplication of data. Only a reference (pointer, or whatever the implementation chooses) is included in the activation record. In the subprogram, the access to the elements of the array can then be computed by the base-address+offset mechanism.

Comment: So arrays are possible because a reference is only stored in the activation record, correct?

Comment: To some extend, yes; especially for those programming languages that build a single static activation record for each subprogram.